# Bring Subview Above Everything But Below Another UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, addsubview

I am trying to place a `UIView` - popupView at the top, and another `UIView` (opaqueView) below popupView but above anything else. PopUpView is connected with an Outlet.

```
func display() {
    popupView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), tableView.center.y);
    self.view.addSubview(popupView)
    popupView.clipsToBounds = true

    let opaqueView = UIView()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    opaqueView.frame.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    opaqueView.alpha = 0.6
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.insertSubview(opaqueView, belowSubview: popupView) 
}
```

Using this approach causes the opaqueView getting placed over everything including the popupView. Instead, I want to have popupView above opaqueView but keep opaqueView above everything else *(view, TabBar, NavBar)*

Comment: Why do you add the `popupView` to `self.view` but `opaqueView` to the `keyWindow`?

Comment: Because, if I don't add `opaqueView` to `keyWindow`, `opaqueView` doesn't get above TabBar and NavigationBar.

Comment: Why not add popupView to keyWindow as well?

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent.insertSubview(child, belowSubview: sibling)` works only when the `sibling` is a direct child of `parent`, so that `child` and `sibling` share the same parent. The current code does not work because `opaqueView` (the child) and `popupView` (the sbiling) have different parents.

That means either ① `popupView` should use the `keyWindow` as the parent, or ② `opaqueView` should use `self.view` as parent. Since you want `opaqueView` be above of everything, option ① is the only solution.